# iOS Swiping functions

Tags: ios, swipe

Good day! I have a question,I have this code for a Single Page application

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint endPosition = [touch locationInView:self.view];

if (self.imageStatus>0)
{
    if (self.startPosition.x < endPosition.x)
    {
        // Right swipe
        CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
        transition.duration = 0.75;
        transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
        transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromLeft;
        transition.delegate = self;
        [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

        [self.view addSubview:myViewController.view];
        self.imageStatus --;
        if (self.imageStatus == 0)
        {
            self.myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_back.png"];

        }
        else
        {
            self.myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"black_back.png"];

        }
    }
}
if (self.imageStatus<2)
{
    if (self.startPosition.x > endPosition.x)
    {
        // Left swipe
        CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
        transition.duration = 0.75;
        transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
        transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromRight;
        transition.delegate = self;
        [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

        [self.view addSubview:myViewController.view];
        self.imageStatus ++;
        if (self.imageStatus == 2)
        {
            self.myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red_back.png"];
        }
        else
        {
            self.myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"black_back.png"];
        }

    }
}
```

when i open the app the default background is black, when i swipe at right it shows the blue_back.png or the blue background, when i swipe back it shows the default background which is black, and when its on black again and i will swipe it left it shows the red_back.png or the red background and vise versa. now what i want is, i will add another page with yellow background next to red, so when im in the default black page, when i swipe to left two times it shows the yellow. and also the swiping function, when i swipe it it takes maybe a second to switch a page, how can i implement the "Realtime Swiping" like in the table view, but horizontal, so it changes page fast. thanks!

Comment: Seems overcomplicated, why not UIPanGestureRecognizer or built in paging in a UIScrollView?

Comment: You have written your code in touchesEnded method so until your swiping is not finished, nothing will happen. This method will execute when you have removed your finger from screen.

Comment: I've tried to put the code under touchesBegin but i got the same result, the page move after i release my finger.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer:

What you want is a paging scrollview. The trick is to add the views are the correct positions in the scrollView and set the scrollviews contentSize correctly. Example with two views:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeBottom;

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 2, self.view.bounds.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    UIView *redView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    redView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    redView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [scrollView addSubview:redView];

    UIView *blueView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
    frame.origin.x = 320;
    blueView.frame = frame;
    blueView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [scrollView addSubview:blueView];
}
```

Old answer:
I would be easier to make use of the build in gesture recognizers. Specifically UIPanGestureRecognizer.

Example:
In viewDidLoad:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:pan];
```

And the action:

```
- (void) myAction:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gestureRec
{
    if (gestureRec.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"ended");
        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint([gestureRec velocityInView:self.view]));
    }
}
```

The state determines when its ended as you want. And you can use the velocityInView to determine right/left and up/down movement

Comment: Im a little unsure if you want the change to happen immediately, when you lift your finger or follow the finger?

Comment: it should follow the finger, like in the home screen if you swipe for the next page

Comment: i tried to add more views like this `UIView *blackiew = [[UIView alloc] init];
    CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
    frame.origin.x = 320;
    blueView.frame = frame;
    blueView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [scrollView addSubview:blackView];

    
    UIView *yellowView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
    frame.origin.x = 320;
    blueView.frame = frame;
    blueView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [scrollView addSubview:yellowView];`
 but im getting some errors

Comment: Well, i cant help you without knowing what errors it is. It seems to me you need to read up on UIScrollView and how to use them. They are essential to understand in order to make iOS apps.