# Xcode Adding more pages on a single view application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Good day mates, I have this app for almost 3 months, I paid a Developer to make this app.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFju-GsN_-s

Since the Developer is not responding anymore to my messages because he get his payment. (lol)
I want to add more pages to this app, that's why i asked this question. [iOS Swiping functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399635/ios-swiping-functions).
But Unfortunately i cant make it work. this is the whole code for the .m file:

```
//
//  MainViewController.m
//  SpreadSheet
//
//  Created by Cai on 8/21/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 quianse. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MainViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.ar = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *Months = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"JAN",@"FEB",@"MAT",@"APR",@"MAY",@"JUN",@"JUL",@"AUG",@"SEP",@"OCT",@"NOV",@"DEC", nil];

    NSDateFormatter *DateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"M"];
    self.currentMonth = [Months objectAtIndex:[[DateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] integerValue]-1];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.currentMonth);
    self.imageStatus = 1;

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    delegate = (SpreadSheetAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [delegate.self.navcon setNavigationBarHidden:true];


    NSString *theURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AkgWFqjLQz0TdDlJMk9JOU9lY2RJWUxONUlodWY3b0E&single=true&gid=%d&output=csv",self.imageStatus];

    NSString *theFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theURL] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",theFile);
    NSArray *theCells = [theFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    for (int i=1; i < [theCells count]; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            NSArray *value =[[theCells objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
            [self.ar addObject:value];
            NSLog(@"%@:%@",[value objectAtIndex:0],[value objectAtIndex:1]);
        }
    }

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void) updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer
{
    NSString *theURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AkgWFqjLQz0TdDlJMk9JOU9lY2RJWUxONUlodWY3b0E&single=true&gid=%d&output=csv",self.imageStatus];

    NSString *theFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theURL] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",theFile);
    NSArray *theCells = [theFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    [self.ar removeAllObjects];
    for (int i=0; i < [theCells count]; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            NSArray *value =[[theCells objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
            [self.ar addObject:value];
            NSLog(@"%@:%@",[value objectAtIndex:0],[value objectAtIndex:1]);
        }
    }
    [self.myTable reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.ar count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    // making the cell as the type of CustomCell
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        //making the object from CustomCell.xib
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = (CustomCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        else
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell_iPad" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = (CustomCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {

        self.lblCurrent.text = [[self.ar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:2];

    }

    cell.URN.text = [[self.ar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];

    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {

        self.lblTitle.text = [[self.ar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:3];

    }

    cell.URN.text = [[self.ar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];



    cell.WorkStatus.text = [[self.ar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:1] ;

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        return 30;
    }
    else
    {
        return 70;
    }
}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    self.startPosition = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint endPosition = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (self.imageStatus>0)
    {
        if (self.startPosition.x < endPosition.x)
        {
            // Right swipe
            CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
            transition.duration = 0.75;
            transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
            transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
            transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromLeft;
            transition.delegate = self;
            [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

            [self.view addSubview:myViewController.view];
            self.imageStatus --;
            if (self.imageStatus == 0)
            {
                self.myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_back.png"];

            }
            else
            {
                self.myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"black_back.png"];

            }
        }
    }
    if (self.imageStatus<2)
    {
        if (self.startPosition.x > endPosition.x)
        {
            // Left swipe
            CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
            transition.duration = 0.75;
            transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
            transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
            transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromRight;
            transition.delegate = self;
            [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

            [self.view addSubview:myViewController.view];
            self.imageStatus ++;
            if (self.imageStatus == 2)
            {
                self.myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red_back.png"];

            }
            else
            {
                self.myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"black_back.png"];

            }

        }
    }

    [self updateCounter:0];
    NSLog(@"%d",[self imageStatus]);
    [[self myTable] reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [_lblCurrent release];
    [_myTable release];
    [_myImage release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

This is the Page arrangements, PAGE1<--PAGE2-->PAGE3 , the page 2 is the default page shows when you open the app, So if you swipe to the right it shows the 3rd page, and if you swipe 2 times ti the left it shows the first page,and also i want the page swiping more realistic, i want when i swipe it of follows the finger like the hope page of the iphone when you're swiping the app icons.

This is the Spreadsheet where the app is getting all its data, 
https://docs.google.com/a/ttttt.us/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkgWFqjLQz0TdDlJMk9JOU9lY2RJWUxONUlodWY3b0E#gid=0
The Tab is arranged base on the page of the app that i want to make,So basically this will be the New app pages will be

`Page5<--Page2<--Page2-->Page3-->Page4`.

I hope you can help me with this :( thank you very much!

Comment: This looks very awkwardly coded.  (I hope you didn't pay much.)  That said, you're going to need a substantially re-worked view controller class from what you've got there, to achieve a really clean effect that you're looking for.  I assume myViewController is an IBOutlet, assigned in the nib.  The red-flag in my mind is myViewController isn't updated... so what is actually showing on PAGE 3 and PAGE 1?

Comment: actually this is the prices for my products, the page one is for Rice grains price, for page 2 is for Vegetables and page 3 is for Dairy products, so you mean we cannot fix this code i have right now? (from now on i will not hire chinese devs lol)

Comment: That's funny! The code could be fixed. I think it requires more in  the way of feature development than programming.  It borders on more effort than should be delivered on a stack overflow answer. It could be fixed, but truly, requires more code of the myViewController object.

Comment: do you have skype? can i add you and lets talk about it?